# Get the weekday from a selected day and not from the current day

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I've seen many ways to get the weekday, but none of them was from a selected day.

```
NSDate * selectedDate = _selectedDate //From Params

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];

NSInteger weekday = [components weekday];
```

How and where should I insert my selected Date?

Since [components setDay:(INTEGER REQUIRED)] 
is it a way to convert the selected day to the current day.. anyone got a clue on this?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HaveYou tried?

```
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:selectedDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateComponents *components = 
 [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit 
        fromDate:selectedDate];
```